# Can an event listener listen two elements? Can you give the handler more parameters?

Tags: google-closure-library

I am experimenting with [`goog.events.listen(src, type, listener, opt_capt, opt_handler)`](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_events_events.js.html#goog.events.listen).
Sometimes I have more than one source but always the same event-type and function that should be called when this event happens (listener).

Should I simply type this once for every source or is there a better way to do it?

As I like to handle this within the object I am creating the listener, I set `opt_handler = this`. I think that in my application it can't happen that two events which have listeners are called at the same moment, so I let `opt_capt = false`.

In my JavaScript-file looks like:

```
var htmlElement = goog.dom.getElement(el[0]);
goog.events.listen(htmlElement, goog.events.EventType.CLICK, this.myFunction, false, this);
```

Now `myFunction` gets only the event as an argument. But I would like to know which htmlElement was clicked. How do I get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument `myFunction` takes will be of type `goog.events.Event`. Its `target` property contains the actual event target, while `currentTarget` contains the object to which the listener was attached.

Comment: Hi nullptr, currentTarget is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! (I would like to vote your answer up, but I have not enough reputation. Sorry.)

Answer (score 1):

you should always be able to use the event via the variable `e` and get it's target, which will be the element you clicked.
But do not put this.myFunction(e) in goog.events.listen. goog.event.myFunction is just fine and you did it right from the beginning. If you later on, want to pass additional parameters to myFunction (and maybe do some currying), look at the `goog.bind` example and also check out `goog.partial`

Greetings,

Jan

```
goog.events.listen(
    htmlElement,
    goog.events.EventType.CLICK,
    this.myFunction,
    false,
    this
);

//alternative
goog.events.listen(
    htmlElement,
    goog.events.EventType.CLICK,
    goog.bind(myFunction, this)
);



myfunction = function(e) {
    //maybe this
    window.console.log(e.target)

    //or this
    var event = e.getBrowserEvent()
    window.console.log(event.target)

}
```